# How to extract several string from log files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to extract several strings from log files. So far so good. But I don't know how to extract only the required details from that result.

Example

A log entry looks like this:

```
(DIAG:XMLRPC)(11:07:01 15/04/2019)(MEM:130590)(TID:3632)(USER:Administrator)(REMOTE:10.67.125.177:59032)(XmlRpc: called method 'QueryCreativeFilterInfoList'.31)
```

I can parse it with the the following code:

```
$output_file = 'C:\Copy-Test\logins.txt'
$regex = 'QueryCreativeFilterInfoList'
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Copy-Test\Logs"

foreach ($file in $files)
 {
    gc $file.FullName | select-string -Pattern $regex | Select-String -Pattern "Administrator" | Out-File -FilePath $output_file -Append
}
```

Now I would like to only output the data, time username but I don't know how. I saw some crazy regex stuff but that was way above of my skill level.

I would appreciate if someone could guide me on this

Comment: Are all the parentheses literal in your example line?

Comment: @LotPings yes, they are part of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to split the log entry string by `)(` delimiter and then print members of a resulting array. Something like this:

```
gc $file.FullName | select-string -Pattern $regex | Select-String -Pattern "Administrator"| foreach {
   $a=$_ -split "\)\("
   "$(($a[1] -split " ")[1,0] -join ' ') $($a[4].substring(5))"
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, that helps.

Now the output looks like this:

11:07:01 15/04/2019
USER:Administrator

Would it futher be possible to format it like this:

Date  Time  Username
----     -----  --------
15/04/2019 11:07:01 Administrator

?